# What is wrong with this sentence? Am I using too many commas?

Tags: commas, syntactic-analysis

> As your personal trainer, it is my mission to work with you to achieve
>   your fitness goals, in a fun, and challenging environment, designed to
>   get you the body you want and deserve.

Does this work? Maybe I've been looking at it too long but it seems awkward to read. Any suggestions are welcome!

Thank you.

Comment: I'd remove the comma after fun. Also "designed to get you...." seems a bit off. What is being designed?

Comment: I thought that too, thanks. The designed was to meant to imply I'm creating a fun environment designed to get the best workout for you.

Comment: I do not believe *fun* is an adjective, nor in my view an apt word to use. The OED dictionary meaning of *funny*, the adjectival inflection of *fun*, is *affording fun, mirth-producing, comical, facetious*. Is that what you mean to include in your 'mission statement'?

Comment: Commas serve a grammatical purpose, namely to guide your reader into parsing your sentence properly.  Thus each comma you use should have a reason for its presence.  Style guides have codified these.  The guides differ and their rules are flexible, but there are some agreed-upon standards.  Can you justify each comma?  I'll start:  The comma after *trainer* serves to separate an introductory adverbial clause from the main clause.

Comment: @WS2 *Fun* has been an adjective for decades with the meaning an interval in spacetime in which people (usually children) will enjoy themselves. *Familiy Fun Time*, *Fun Time With Bonzo*, *Fun Time With Numbers* -- these are all found with the Ngram viewer.  Try it:  you'll have a fun time.  It's a particularly apt locution for an ad for these services, which attempts to convince people that they will enjoy what is likely to be nothing short of a misery.

Comment: @deadrat: well, "fun" could just be a noun used being used as a noun adjunct in those phrases (like the word *family*). But there are other clearly adjectival uses, like "it wasn't as fun as I thought it would be."

Comment: @sumelic Good points.  I should have said that *fun* has been an acceptable modifier for a long time as a noun adjunct in locutions like "fun time."

Comment: @deadrat: and then again, sentences like the one I just listed, with fun as an adjective, are often easily replaceable with noun uses: simply adding a "much" makes it a noun ("as much fun as...). The forms with "much" are more common in [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+much+fun+as%2Cas+fun+as&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cas%20much%20fun%20as%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cas%20fun%20as%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @sumelic Ain't English fun?

Comment: @deadrat Part of my argument is that *fun* is never anything other than *an apt locution* - as you so eloquently put it - *for services, which attempt to convince people that they will enjoy what is likely to be nothing short of misery*. Take, for example, this use from 1879 *W. J. Barry Up & Down vii. 51   We..had a good passage to Hong-Kong. When we arrived, the first Chinese war with Britain had broken out, and there was every appearance of plenty of fun to be shortly had with the Chinkies*. (continued)

Comment: @deadrat I am not sure if  *Familiy Fun Time, Fun Time With Bonzo, Fun Time With Numbers* are in the same category - but they sound like misery to me*.

Comment: @WS2  Are you saying that *fun* is always used ironically?  Given that the word rhymes with "sun," it's usage is straightforward in song lyrics from the sublime (Blondie) to the ridiculous (Terry Jacks).  And I'm not so sure about your 1879 example.  We're talking about the heyday of the British Empire, when taxing all foreigners living abroad and shooting those who demurred *was* fun, at least for the British.

Comment: @deadrat I think what I mean is that it is a word, which if someone used it more than once in a two-hour interview, I might conclude that they didn't have a very wide vocabulary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

> As your personal trainer, it is my mission to work with you to achieve
>   your fitness goals in a fun and challenging environment designed to
>   get you the body you want and deserve.

By removing the comma after "environment," *that is* is implied: ("...environment *that is* designed..."). You could leave the comma there, which would make "designed to get..." additional (non-essential) information.

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that it is the environment being designed, I’d say:

> As your personal trainer, it is my mission to work with you to achieve
>   your fitness goals in a fun and challenging environment, which is
>   designed to get you the body you want and deserve.

Another option, depending on what you think of the style, might be:

> …a fun and challenging environment – an environment designed to get
>   you the body you want and deserve.